# Unable to add CSS and JS files in express using hbs && On Console : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Handlebars version 4.1.2 in express for rendering HTML.I am unable to load CSS and JavaScript files. I don't know why it's not working. I tried many ways to load local CSS file via every possible path. I am new to express please do help.

And on console it is showing:
`main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Here is my index.hbs code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
        {{>header}}
        <h1> {{title}}</h1>
        {{>footer}}
        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

And this is my express code :

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const hbs = require('hbs')
const app = express();

const viewPath = path.join(__dirname,'../templates/views')
const partialPath = path.join(__dirname,'../templates/partials')

//Setting  up the Paths
app.set('view engine' , 'hbs')
app.set('views' , viewPath)
hbs.registerPartials(partialPath)

app.get('/', ( req, res) =>{
    res.render('index',{
        title:'Home Page'
    })
})
```

Here is my folder structure :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXch5.png)

Comment: CSS and JS are STATIC files, where did you declare your static directory in express? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @phoenix Feel free to answer your own question for others.